# PhpStorm: different colors for quotation marks/apostrophes and string itself

Tags: colors, themes, phpstorm

I want to differ the color of the string from the color of the quotation marks/apostrophes in PhpStorm.

For example in: `echo "Hello world";` quotation marks should be green and *Hello world* violet, as shown here:

[image: sample]

Is there such possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware -- it's not currently possible.

I found this [WI-27547](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27547) ticket .. which for some reason got marked as duplicate of [IDEABKL-6214](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6214).

I suggest to ask developers directly there (in first ticket -- why it's duplicate .. or when it will be implemented in 2nd one).